# how to make a Parameter Constructor to initialize the row and column leading to a Square Matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix

i am having problem in making a parameterized constructor to initialize row and column leading to square matrix. so far, i have intialized row and column to 2 and dynamically allocated memory using new operator.

here is my code till now:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class matrix {

    int row, column;
    matrix()
    {
        row = 2;
        column = 2;
    }
    int **array;

        array = new int*[row];
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
           array[i]=new int[column];
        }
};
```

and my question to do is this :

Create a class called Matrix containing “row”, “col” as integers and one integer
pointer called “array”. Include functions in the class for the following specifications. 
Use new and delete operators to allocate memory dynamically depending on row and
column values.

i) Default Constructor to initialize the row and column to 2.

ii)One Parameter Constructor to initialize the row and column leading to a
Square Matrix.

Edit :

I have completed the code, here it is. is it correct :

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<iomanip>
 using namespace std;

 //Create a class sqMatrix
 class sqMatrix
 {
    private:
       int **matrix;
       int dim;
    public:
       sqMatrix(int=5);
       sqMatrix(const sqMatrix&);
       ~sqMatrix();
       sqMatrix operator+(const sqMatrix&);
       sqMatrix operator-(const sqMatrix&);
       sqMatrix operator*(int);
       sqMatrix operator*(const sqMatrix&);
       sqMatrix operator^(const sqMatrix&);
       friend istream& operator>>(istream&,sqMatrix&);
       friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,sqMatrix);
 };
 //Destructor
 sqMatrix::~sqMatrix()
 {
    for(int i=0;i<sqMatrix::dim;i++)
    {
       delete[] (sqMatrix::matrix)[i];
    }
 }
 //Parameterized constructor
 sqMatrix::sqMatrix(int dim)
 {
    sqMatrix::matrix=new int*[dim];
    for(int j=0;j<dim;j++)
    {
       sqMatrix::matrix[j]=new int[dim];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<dim;j++)
          sqMatrix::matrix[i][j]=0;
    }
    sqMatrix::dim=dim;
 }
 //Copy constructor
 sqMatrix::sqMatrix(const sqMatrix &mat)
 {
    sqMatrix::matrix=new int*[mat.dim];
    for(int j=0;j<mat.dim;j++)
    {
       sqMatrix::matrix[j]=new int[mat.dim];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<mat.dim;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<mat.dim;j++)
          sqMatrix::matrix[i][j]=mat.matrix[i][j];
    }
    sqMatrix::dim=mat.dim;
 }
 //This function is used to perform the addition operation
 sqMatrix sqMatrix::operator+(const sqMatrix &mat)
 {
    sqMatrix tmp(mat.dim);
    for(int i=0;i<mat.dim;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<mat.dim;j++)
       {
          tmp.matrix[i][j]=sqMatrix::matrix[i][j]+mat.matrix[i][j];
       }
    }
    return tmp;
 }
 //This function is used to perform the subtraction operation
 sqMatrix sqMatrix::operator-(const sqMatrix &mat)
 {
    sqMatrix tmp(mat.dim);
    for(int i=0;i<mat.dim;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<mat.dim;j++)
       {
          tmp.matrix[i][j]=sqMatrix::matrix[i][j]-mat.matrix[i][j];
       }
    }
    return tmp;
 }
 //This function is used to perform the multiplication operation with a scalar value
 sqMatrix sqMatrix::operator*(int c)
 {
    sqMatrix tmp(sqMatrix::dim);
    for(int i=0;i<sqMatrix::dim;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<sqMatrix::dim;j++)
          tmp.matrix[i][j] = sqMatrix::matrix[i][j] * c;
    }
    return tmp;
 }
 //This function is used to perform the multiplication operation between two square matrices
 sqMatrix sqMatrix::operator*(const sqMatrix &mat)
 {
    sqMatrix tmp(sqMatrix::dim);
    for(int i=0;i<sqMatrix::dim;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<sqMatrix::dim;j++)
       {
          tmp.matrix[i][j]=0;
          for(int k=0;k<sqMatrix::dim;k++)
          {
             tmp.matrix[i][j]=tmp.matrix[i][j]+sqMatrix::matrix[i][k]*mat.matrix[k][j];
          }
       }
    }
    return tmp;
 }
 //This function is used to get transpose of a square matrix
 sqMatrix sqMatrix::operator^(const sqMatrix &mat)
 {
    for(int i=0;i<sqMatrix::dim;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<sqMatrix::dim;j++)
          mat.matrix[i][j]=sqMatrix::matrix[j][i];
    }
    return mat;
 }
 //Overload >>(cin) operator which takes a square matrix as input
 istream& operator>>(istream &s,sqMatrix &mat)
 {
    cout<<"Enter "<<mat.dim*mat.dim<<" Elements :-"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<mat.dim;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<mat.dim;j++)
       {
          cout<<"Element at row "<<i+1<<" col "<<j+1<<" : ";
          s>>mat.matrix[i][j];
       }
    }
 }
 //Overload <<(cout) operator which displays a square matrix
 ostream& operator<<(ostream &s,sqMatrix mat)
 {
    for(int i=0;i<mat.dim;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<mat.dim;j++)
       {
          s<<setw(10);
          s<<mat.matrix[i][j];
       }
       cout<<"\n";
    }
 }
 int main()
 {
    int dim;

    cout<<"Enter dimension:";
    cin>>dim;

    sqMatrix test(dim);
    cin>>test;
    cout<<"Original Matrix:"<<endl;
    cout<<test;

    sqMatrix cpy(test);
    cout<<"Copy of the orginal Matrix:"<<endl;
    cout<<cpy;

    sqMatrix test1(dim);
    cout<<"Enter another matrix to add with the original:\n";
    cin>>test1;

    cout<<"Result of addition:\n";
    sqMatrix cpy1=test+test1;
    cout<<cpy1;

    sqMatrix test2(dim);
    cout<<"Enter another matrix to subtract with the original:\n";
    cin>>test2;

    cout<<"Result of subtraction:\n";
    sqMatrix cpy2=test-test2;
    cout<<cpy2;

    int sc;
    cout<<"Enter a scalar value:";
    cin>>sc;

    cout<<"multiplying with scalar value with the original: "<<endl<<endl;
    sqMatrix cpy3=test*sc;
    cout<<cpy3;

    sqMatrix test3(dim);
    cout<<"Enter another matrix to multiply with the original:\n";
    cin>>test3;

    cout<<"Result of multiplication:\n";
    sqMatrix cpy4=test*test3;
    cout<<cpy4;

    sqMatrix test4(dim);
    cout<<"\nTranspose of original matrix:\n";
    sqMatrix cpy5=test^test4;
    cout<<cpy5;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This code won't compile. Also the question asks for an integer pointer, you are using an pointer to integer pointer.

Comment: `matric(int dim)` as the signature for the b) constructor should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions for improvement:

- A general suggestion:

  When you want to use a member data of a class, it's better to use `this->` rather than `sqMatrix::`. E.g. Use

  ```
  this->dim = dim;
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  sqMatrix::dim = dim;
  ```

  The second form is used when (1) You have a static member of the class (this is a convention, not a necessity), or (2) You need to use a member of the base class and not the member of the current class with the same name (this is a necessity).
- You need to deallocate `matrix` in the destructor.

  ```
  //Destructor
  sqMatrix::~sqMatrix()
  {
     for(int i=0;i<sqMatrix::dim;i++)
     {
        // delete[] (sqMatrix::matrix)[i];
        // Simplify to:
        delete [] matrix[i];
     }
     delete [] matrix;  // This was a missing line
  }
  ```
- I would recommend not to use `operator^` to transpose the matrix. You can just create a function named `transpose`. The syntax

  ```
  sqMatrix cpy5=test.transpose();
  ```

  is more readable than

  ```
  sqMatrix cpy5=test^test4;
  ```

  The current implementation also suffers from the fact that you are modifying the second argument in place even though it is passed using `sqMatrix const&.` I am going to suggest

  ```
  sqMatrix sqMatrix::transpose() const
  {
     sqMatrix tmp(this->dim);
     for(int i=0;i<this->dim;i++)
     {
        for(int j=0;j<this->dim;j++)
           tmp.matrix[i][j]=this->matrix[j][i];
     }
     return tmp;
  }
  ```